# LINQ part of string is contained in list members

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of strings that contain partial values, ie

```
var list = new List<string>{"A/B", "C/D"};
```

And in my DB I have records such as

1. A/B/X
2. X/C/V/B
3. G/H/J
4. C/D/D/C
5. A/C
6. A/B

So I would like to now query all the items from DB that start with any of values contained in `list`. From the example 1, 4 and 6 should be returned.

I have other logic that is doing the same thing but other way around, so I can query like `.Where(x => list.Contains(x))`, but can't figure out how to select values that start with items contained in list using LINQ.

Comment: Are you using EF? Could you show your entities in that case?

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970899/linq-to-sql-query-where-a-string-startswith-an-element-from-a-generic-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF to get the data from your DB, you can do the following:

```
var list = new List<string>{"A/B", "C/D"};
var query= context.YourDbSet.Where(e=>list.Any(a=>e.Column.StartWith(a)));// Column is a property of type string.
```

Anyways the main idea here is check if your items start with one of the elements of `list`, you can do that using `StartWith` method of `string`. If your `items` collection is a list of strings then do this:

```
var query= items.Where(e=>list.Any(a=>e.StartWith(a)));
```